# How to replicate number of rows in dataframe1 to match n rows in dataframe 2 in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, csv

I just started learning Python a few months ago and just started using StackOverflow as well, please bear with me:
We have the two data frames:

**df1:**

```
    0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4  
    1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0
    6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0
```

**df2:**

```
    Sequence, dataset_ID  
    1,1  
    2,4  
    10,5
```

I am using python iterrows function to transpose df1 into:

```
for ind,row in df1.iterrows():
    row.to_csv(path+'\df1Transposed')
```

**df1Transposed:**

```
    0.1,1.0
    0.2,2.0  
    0.3,3.0  
    0.4,4.0
    0.1,6.0
    0.2,7.0  
    0.3,8.0  
    0.4,9.0
```

I am trying to find a good way to group/replicate each row in df2 to match the number of rows in df1 transposed. For example, 1 transposed header and row in df 1 creates 4 rows and two columns in df1Transposed (0.1-0.4) and repeats again for the next row in df1. So the first row in df2 should repeat 4 times and then the second row should repeat another 4 times.

**dfout:**

```
Sequence, dataset_ID,V,I
1,1,0.1,1.0
1,1,0.2,2.0  
1,1,0.3,3.0  
1,1,0.4,4.0  
2,4,0.1,6.0  
2,4,0.2,7.0  
2,4,0.3,8.0  
2,4,0.4,9.0
```

Comment: what happens to the third row in df2 ?

Comment: for the transposed part, u can avoid iterrows with this : ```pd.concat([df1.iloc[:2].T,
                       df1.iloc[::2].T.set_axis([0,1],axis=1)],ignore_index=True)```

Comment: Apologies, we can ignore the third row for the time being - what's shown is just a part of my entire dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of numpy's  `repeat` and `arange` to get the index, then concatenate the two dataframes horizontally.

First, get the transpose thanks to @sammywemmy handy one-liner:

```
df1_T = pd.concat([df1.iloc[:2].T,
                   df1.iloc[::2].T.set_axis([0,1],axis=1)],ignore_index=True)
```

Second get the length of the transpose dataframe, select the number of rows you want to include from df2 and use the functions mentioned above:

```
df_1_l = df1_T.shape[0]
no_rows_from_df2 = 2
index = np.repeat(np.arange(no_rows_from_df2), df_1_l//rows_df2)

df3 = pd.concat([df1_T.reset_index(drop=True),
             df2.iloc[index].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
df3

#     0 1   Sequence  dataset_ID
# 0 0.1 1.0   1       1
# 1 0.2 2.0   1       1
# 2 0.3 3.0   1       1
# 3 0.4 4.0   1       1
# 4 0.1 6.0   2       4
# 5 0.2 7.0   2       4
# 6 0.3 8.0   2       4
# 7 0.4 9.0   2       4
```

Few things, this works because the length of df1_T is a mutiple of the selected number of rows in df2, if for example you would like to repeat rows `0,1,2` then the length of `df1` should be `3, 6, 9, 12 ...`